# Jenkins - Xvfb Plugin - Start socket error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, fatal-error, socketexception, xvfb

Everything was working good until today, but now I'm seeing an error while my Jenkins (1.585) job, which is running/using Xvfb plugin, it's giving me the following error.

Any idea, why it's coming. I tried many times.

```
15:00:07 Xvfb starting$ Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -fbdir /production/home/koba/JSlaves/loki10_1/xvfb-2015-02-09_14-59-58-7153097250048722116.fbdir
15:00:07 _XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
15:00:07 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
15:00:07 
15:00:07 Fatal server error:
15:00:07 Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running
15:00:07 unlink: No such file or directory
15:01:07 unlink  failed, errno 2
15:01:07 ERROR: Xvfb failed to start, consult the lines above for errors
```

Running ps -eAf on the box (a RHEL box), shows a valid running service and no other "already running display service":

```
/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8
```

If Jenkins Xvfb plugin's works, then you'd usually see an output similar to the one shown below (for the ps command):

```
usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8
Xvfb :11 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -fbdir /production/home/koba/JSlaves/loki10_1/xvfb-2015-02-09_14-37-38-3214202920310710589.fbdir
```

Where :11 is a random Display number that Jenkins Xvfb plugin is generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, never mind.

The following did the trick. Now, Xvfb instance is getting created successfully.

```
/etc/init.d/xvfb stop; echo hola!; /etc/init.d/xvfb start; ps -eAf|grep -i xvfb
```